# Linux suppress find error in bash script combined with file delete

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a one line script which works fine but...

```
find $HOME/html/mydir/downloads/sec/*.zip  -mtime 2 -exec rm {} \;
```

It generates an error if there are no files found and my web host then sends me a pointless email. So I want to suppress the error message if the 'error' is "No such file or directory"

I was thinking I could do something like this:

```
find $HOME/html/mydir/downloads/sec/*.zip 2>&1 | grep -v "No such file or directory"
```

...but I don't know how to combine this with my current script such that the output of find will still go to exec if there -are- files found (or if there is another type of error).

Comment: John1024's answer is basically correct, but an alternative is to check if any files match the mask with something like `if echo DirPath/*.zip|grep -q '\*'; then echo No files; else find ... ; fi`. Note that the error message is generated if no files match the mask: if files exist their age will determine whether any are then found.

Comment: @AFH: That would fail in the (unlikely) case that there are file(s) whose name(s) contain literal asterisk(s).

Comment: @G-Man - Quite right. I did actually think of that, but after checking a few things I forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
find $HOME/html/mydir/downloads/sec/ -maxdepth 1 -name '*.zip' -mtime 2 -delete
```

`find` does not have a problem if a search turns up finds no files.  It does have a problem if the directory/files that you specify on the command line do not exist.  The solution, as shown above, is to specify a directory that exists and ask it to search for `.zip` files.

Also, note that `-exec rm {} \;` can be replaced with `-delete`.

By the way, `-mtime 2` will only be true for files that are (rounded to an integer) 2 days old.  If you want to delete files that are *more than* two days olds, then use `-mtime +2`.

Comment: A good answer, but I would add `-maxdepth 1` in case there are further subdirectories containing zip files, as without this clause more files would be returned than the original command.

Comment: @AFH Good point.  Answer updated to use `-maxdepth 1`.

Comment: @John1024: Question: you have the -name parameter twice in your answer. Is that intentional or a typo?

Comment: @jchwebdev Yes, that was a typo.  Thanks!  Answer updated.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: don't use `-exec`.

`$ find $HOME/html/mydir/downloads/sec/*.zip  -mtime 2 | xargs -r rm`